# ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope. Discord.JS

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im getting this error whenever I try to run my discord.js bot. It was working a few weeks ago when I was messing around with it trying out a few stuff. Im a newbie so bear with me with little mistakes and such.

Error Im getting :

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\cubix\Documents\Discord Bots\discordbot-photos\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/interactions/slashCommands/photo2.js:1:44
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async SlashManager (file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/structures/managers/slashCommands.js:14:35)
    at async file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/bot.js:50:5
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\cubix\Documents\Discord Bots\discordbot-photos\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/interactions/slashCommands/photo2.js:1:44
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async SlashManager (file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/structures/managers/slashCommands.js:14:35)
    at async file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/bot.js:50:5
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\cubix\Documents\Discord Bots\discordbot-photos\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/interactions/slashCommands/photo2.js:1:44
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async SlashManager (file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/structures/managers/slashCommands.js:14:35)
    at async file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/bot.js:50:5
(node:3968) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 3)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\cubix\Documents\Discord Bots\discordbot-photos\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/interactions/slashCommands/photo2.js:1:44
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:218:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:329:24)
    at async SlashManager (file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/src/structures/managers/slashCommands.js:14:35)
    at async file:///C:/Users/cubix/Documents/Discord%20Bots/discordbot-photos/bot.js:50:5
(node:3968) PromiseRejectionHandledWarning: Promise rejection was handled asynchronously (rejection id: 4
```

Ive tried changing the "module" in the package.json to "commonjs" as suggested by a few people online which resulted in the error:

```
(node:11992) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
C:\Users\cubix\Documents\Discord Bots\discordbot-photos\bot.js:1
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } from "discord.js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:77:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1287:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1339:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1434:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49

Node.js v21.5.0
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.